# QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have been trying to run the nearest distance to hub points process (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdistancetonearesthubpoints) in Jupyter notebook.

As of the data, I have 2 geojson files (polygon) i.e. inputvector2 and inputvector3 in this case. I have attached the error I get as image below.                        **PS: I am a newbie**

[image: Error encountered]

Code snippet

```
vertice_out = r"D:\nearesthub.geojson"
# just delete the output if exist
if os.path.exists(vertice_out):
    os.remove(vertice_out)
else:
    pass
params = {
    'INPUT': inputvector2,
    'HUBS' : inputvector3,
    'FIELD' : 'name',
    'UNIT' : 0,
    'OUTPUT': vertice_out
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
processing.run("qgis:distancetonearesthubpoints", params, feedback=feedback)
```

Comment: The reason for the error was some invalid geometries in the geodataframe. As for this issue, I ran another qgis algorithm ("native:fixgeometries") for both the geodataframes before running the above script. After that, the above script ran totally fine.